# UI scaling in different iPad versions and iPad models?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, ios8, storyboard

I will launch my App for the first time targeting iPads (universal). My problem is I came across some inequalities in how the UI scales at different iOS-versions and iPad models. This is the list of different models form the iPad simulator I tested it against:

iPad 2 7.0

iPad 2 7.1

iPad 2 8.1

iPad Air 7.0

iPad Air 7.1

iPad Air 8.1 (scales perfectly)

iPad Retina 7.0

iPad Retina 7.1

iPad Retina 8.1 (scales perfectly)

*Some examples and results can be seen in the Pictures below. The inequalities how the tabBar and UISlider scales in different iOS versions and models:*

[image]

My questions are.

**1**.How come my tabBar background picture is so messed up in example iPad 2 iOS 7.0 and not iPad Air 8.1 ? (Is it different dimensions I need to consider while using a background picture?)

**2**.Can I possibly target different models / versions of iPads and fix my UI like you do with macros for iPhone6 / iPhone6P ? And then how?

**3**.How come the interface tabBar background picture scales differently in **iPad Air 7.0** and **iPad Air 7.1**?. These are the same iPad models with the only inequalities in different iOS versions?

All help is appreciated / Regards

Comment: Are you using Auto Layout? No one can give you an answer until we see that and how you define your interface.

Comment: All I do is using AutoLayout and pictures of normal size or @2x.png. I find it very odd the same pictures gets scaled differently in for example iOS 7.0 and iOS 7.1 in iPad Air scenario. For tabBar I do [tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage ImageNamed:xxxx.png]];

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to adapt programmatic elements (like image as you mentioned), you can add conditional statements to the relevant UI objects like this:

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].model == desiredModel) {

    // Code here (e.g. self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];

} else {

    // Every other case

}
```

If I need to repeat this process often, I normally set up a BOOL and run a check in viewDidLoad (isPad = YES / NO) and then lay out using that conditional. Since you are only targeting iPad, you can set up a similar BOOL for whatever devices need certain elements.

Having said all that, I know very little about *how* you are setting up your interface (programmatically, storyboard, xibs), so that's all I can offer.